# "На смехотворной зарплате" (осталась), - предлог годится?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

> Престарелая дама, что служила здесь смотрительницей до самой смерти, в
>   какой-то момент **осталась единственным сотрудником на смехотворной
>   зарплате** и махнула рукой на эту гору работы.

На окладе - да, со смехотворной - да, а тута как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже не знаю... Как будто бы и не очень смотрится, но и не просторечно. По крайней мере, приемлемо в связи с нашей современной действительностью. Ведь говорим же мы "перевести на меньшую зарплату"? Значит, можно и "сотрудник на зарплате". По-моему, в бытовом смысле допустимо, здесь же не книжная речь - разговорная.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение **"сидеть на зарплате"** существует. И здесь предлог **на** по-моему звучит органично, с учётом, конечно, регистра, который его допускает.